# Rigidbody physics

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, collider

I'm currently working on a 2D game, where character is moving around a circle, but for now it's made with rb.MovePosition(), and I need to make it somehow else to detect colliders the way I want. For now my character is shaking beside the wall and simply go through it.

Here's my code:

```
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        _oldAngle = _angle;
        _angle += _speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
        _oldAngle = _angle;
        _angle -= _speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    var position = new Vector2(Mathf.Cos(_angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad), 
    Mathf.Sin(_angle  * Mathf.Deg2Rad));
    _rb.MovePosition(_startPosition + position * _radius);
}
```

I’ve tried to switch rigidbody types, add rigidbody to the wall, edit colliders, nothing helps.

Any thoughts?

[Character screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeVIs.jpg)

Comment: You want to limit the angle rotation to between +90 degrees (y-axis) and -270 degrees.  Using _speed * Time.deltaTime will give infinite degrees.

Comment: @jdweng thank you for advice, but i have no clue how to do it :( Is Mathf.Clamp() will be helpful?

Comment: It depends on your speed and update time.  If you are updating slowly you may rotate multiple times and then you use modular arithmetic using 360 degrees.  If you are updating multiple times for every rotation than Clamp may work.

Comment: Still can't find a solution. Do you have any hints for me by any chance?

Comment: Zero degrees is at positive X Axis.  The wall is at 90 degrees (or -270 degrees).  To stop going through the wall you have to limit the angle to positive 90 degrees and -270 degrees.